# Infinite Series with factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble manipulating the function of this series which has factorials to show that it converges or diverges using the ratio test.

The series is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(k!)^2}{(2k)!}$.  The following are the steps I used, but I made a mistake expanding/canceling the factorial portion somewhere which I can't figure out..

First write the limit using ratio test:
$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{((k+1)!)^2}{(2k+2)!}\cdot\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$$
Expand to cancel factorials:
$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{((k+1)(k!))^2}{(2k+2)(2k+1){(2k)}!}\cdot\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$$

Then after canceling I got:

$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$$

This would result in polynomials of the same degree in the numerator and denominator, and the coefficients of the $k^2$ term would be 1 and 4, so I said the series converges because $\dfrac{1}{4} < 1$ which means the series converges by the ratio test.  However, the series is supposed to diverge according to my book.  I don't have much practice working with factorials so I know my mistake must be somewhere in there.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your work is correct. Seemingly your text is incorrect.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha confirms convergence: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28i%3D0%2C+infinity%2C+%28i%21%29+*+%28i%21%29%2F%282i%29%21

Comment: The work above is correct. The series is convergent.

Comment: Yep, looks good to me as well.

Comment: $\binom{2k}{k}\sim\frac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$. Thus, the terms of your series are $\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi k}}{4^k}$ which shows why the ratio test gives $\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation everyone.  Although rare, I guess the text book can be wrong from time to time.  ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integers $1 \leq j \leq k,$ we find $(j + k) \geq 2 j.$ As a result, 
$$ \frac{(k!)^2}{(2k)!} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{j}{j+k} \leq  \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^k} $$

Detail, $$  \frac{j+k}{j} = 1 + \frac{k}{j} \geq 1 + 1 = 2,  $$ so
$$ \frac{j}{j+k} \leq \frac{1}{2}  $$

Answer (score 5):

> *The series is supposed to diverge according to my book*.

Unless that book is the Bible, I suggest you take any information contained therein with a grain of salt. :-) As already noted by the other commenters, the series converges, so you did alright. More to the point, its value is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n\choose n}=\frac13+\frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{27}$ . We know this because of the more general result $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{{2n\choose n}n^2}=2\arcsin^2x\quad\iff\quad\Big(1-x^2\Big)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{2n\choose n}=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arcsin x,$$ $\quad$ which can be deduced by integrating the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) expansion of $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\arcsin'x$.